# PDF document- object encoding

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to understand how PDF objects are encoded.
Example - PDF doc with 1 page of text in english has following objects (this PDF was created using PDFLaTex tool):

```
obj 3 0 
obj 8 0 
obj 11 0
obj 5 0 
obj 12 0
```

Could someone explain me the concept behind the object ID generation, it doesn't have an order and I am not able to figure out the concept behind it.

Comment: There is no 'logic' to the object numbers in a PDF file. Generally the creator assigns object numbers as required, starting at 1. Occasionally a creating application may find that it reserves a number, but doesn't actually need it and so leaves it as free. Edited PDF files can have objects 'deleted', by simply marking the object as free in the free list and removing references to it from other objects, but leaving the definition in the file, making it possible to later 'undelete' the object. There's no point in looking for a pattern in the IDs.

Comment: @KenS, thanks for your reply. So according to your explanation, PDF creation tools dont follow any logic to generate objects and do it randomly???

Comment: Not randomly, ordinarily when creating a PDF you start by creating object 1, then object 2 etc. So you might (for example) find that a given tool always creates the first page with object number 3, say. But a different tool might create all the page content first, and then create the page object, so its object number would be essentially random. Since there's also no way to know what objects (XObjects, patterns, color spaces etc) any page is going to need, you can't predict anything about the object numbers. Its not an encoding as such, just a unique ID for each object.